# NoReplicaOnlineException with Kafka 0.8.1.1

Tags: apache-kafka

I am running Kafka 0.8.1.1 with one Zookeeper and one broker. I created a partition 'test2' as below:

/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic test2

I noticed this exception in the state-change.log. Why is this occuring ? Should I be running more brokers if I have more than one partition ?

Exception:

kafka.common.NoReplicaOnlineException: No replica for partition [test2,2] is alive. Live brokers are: [Set()], Assigned replicas are: [List(0)]

```
    at kafka.controller.OfflinePartitionLeaderSelector.selectLeader(PartitionLeaderSelector.scala:61)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.electLeaderForPartition(PartitionStateMachine.scala:336)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.kafka$controller$PartitionStateMachine$$handleStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:185)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:99)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine$$anonfun$triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange$3.apply(PartitionStateMachine.scala:96)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:743)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:95)

    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:772)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$$anon$1.foreach(HashTable.scala:157)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:190)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:45)

    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:95)

    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:742)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.triggerOnlinePartitionStateChange(PartitionStateMachine.scala:96)

    at kafka.controller.PartitionStateMachine.startup(PartitionStateMachine.scala:68)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.onControllerFailover(KafkaController.scala:312)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:162)

    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.elect(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:63)

    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:49)

    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)

    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)

    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)

    at kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector.startup(ZookeeperLeaderElector.scala:47)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply$mcV$sp(KafkaController.scala:637)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:633)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController$$anonfun$startup$1.apply(KafkaController.scala:633)

    at kafka.utils.Utils$.inLock(Utils.scala:538)

    at kafka.controller.KafkaController.startup(KafkaController.scala:633)

    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:96)

    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:34)

    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)

    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
```